# How to use two foreach to insert data in database

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-query-builder

I have two arrays from my view.I need to insert their data corresponding to each other.

Below is the My view

```
<?php foreach ($seats as $seat):?>

        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat_id[]" value=<?php echo $seat->seatNumber;?>></td>
            <td><?php echo $seat->seatLabel;?></td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="seat_label[]" value="<?php echo $seat->seatLabel;?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach;?>
```

From above view seat_id and seat_label carries values that have to be stored in database

This is my controller

```
if($this->form_validation->run()){
            $seat_ids = $this->input->post("seat_id[]");
            $seat_labels = $this->input->post("seat_label[]");
            $busNumber = $this->input->post("busNumber");
            $bookingDate = $this->input->post("bookingDate");
            $reportingTime = $this->input->post("reportingTime");
            $departureTime = $this->input->post("departureTime");
            $this->load->model('Queries');
     $insert = $this->Queries->saveMessage($seat_ids, $seat_labels, $busNumber, $bookingDate, $reportingTime, $departureTime);
```

This is My model

```
public function saveMessage($seat_ids, $seat_labels, $busNumber, $bookingDate, $reportingTime, $departureTime){

    foreach($seat_ids as $seat_id )
          foreach($seat_labels as $seat_label ){
    {
        $record = array(
        'seatNumber' => $seat_id, 
        'seatLabel'  => $seat_label,
        'bookingDate' => $bookingDate,
        'reportingTime' => $reportingTime,
        'departureTime' => $departureTime, 
        'busNumber' => $busNumber,
        'seatUse' => 'Enabled',
        'seatStatus' => 'Available',);
        $this->db->insert('schedule', $record);
    }
```

Comment: So you basically want the `foreach()` loops to run paralleel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

Use `insert_batch` instead of `insert` like this :

```
public function saveMessage($seat_ids, $seat_labels, $busNumber, $bookingDate, $reportingTime, $departureTime)
{

    foreach($seat_ids as $key => $seat_id )
    {
            $record[] = array(
            'seatNumber' => $seat_id, 
            'seatLabel'  => $seat_labels[$key],
            'bookingDate' => $bookingDate,
            'reportingTime' => $reportingTime,
            'departureTime' => $departureTime, 
            'busNumber' => $busNumber,
            'seatUse' => 'Enabled',
            'seatStatus' => 'Available');
    }
    $this->db->insert_batch('schedule', $record);
}
```

For more :https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data

Comment: sir please explain it with adding comment also, its my request.

Comment: and what is the difference between `insert_batch()` & `insert()` ??

Answer (score 0):

your code should read

```
 foreach($seat_ids as $seat_id ){
     foreach($seat_labels as $seat_label ){
        $record = array(
        'seatNumber' => $seat_id, 
        'seatLabel'  => $seat_label,
        'bookingDate' => $bookingDate,
        'reportingTime' => $reportingTime,
        'departureTime' => $departureTime, 
        'busNumber' => $busNumber,
        'seatUse' => 'Enabled',
        'seatStatus' => 'Available',);
        $this->db->insert('schedule', $record);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your the keys from `$seat_id` and `$seat_label` match you can do it with only one foreach like this:

```
foreach($seat_ids as $seat_key => $seat_id ) {
    $record = array(
    'seatNumber' => $seat_id, 
    'seatLabel'  => $seat_label[$seat_key],
    'bookingDate' => $bookingDate,
    'reportingTime' => $reportingTime,
    'departureTime' => $departureTime, 
    'busNumber' => $busNumber,
    'seatUse' => 'Enabled',
    'seatStatus' => 'Available',);
    $this->db->insert('schedule', $record);
}
```

Comment: What about the incorrect id-label relation when not all ids are ticked?

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are using JSON to submit the form data and order among array is maintained.

You may try :

```
$i = 0;
foreach($seat_ids as $seat_id )
{
    $record = array(
    'seatNumber' => $seat_id, 
    'seatLabel'  => $seat_labels[$i],
    'bookingDate' => $bookingDate,
    'reportingTime' => $reportingTime,
    'departureTime' => $departureTime, 
    'busNumber' => $busNumber,
    'seatUse' => 'Enabled',
    'seatStatus' => 'Available',);
    $this->db->insert('schedule', $record);
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Currently the form does not have a seat-label relation. if you do not tick all ids, then the labels after that will correspond to the wrong id (i.e. the ids' posted array is smaller than the labels' array)

Hence you will have to introduce the necessary relation into the form names:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="seat[{index}][id]" value="{id}">
<input type="hidden" name="seat[{index}][label]" value="{label}">
```

If that submits, you can now check if both boxes were ticked

```
// using $_POST for simplicity
$seats = array_filter($_POST['seat'], function (array $row) {
    return count($row) === 2;
});
```

Now you have an array with corresponding ids/labels where only one loop is needed.

EDIT: overlooked that the second input is a hidden field, but that didn't affect the problem at all.